# Error in filtering groupby results in pandas

Tags: pandas

I am trying to filter groupby results in pandas using the example provided at:

http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/groupby.html#filtration

but getting the following error (pandas 0.12):

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-12-d0014484ff78> in <module>()
      1 grouped = my_df.groupby('userID')
----> 2 grouped.filter(lambda x: len(x) >= 5)

/Users/zz/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/groupby.pyc in filter(self, func, dropna, *args, **kwargs)
   2092                 res = path(group)
   2093 
-> 2094             if res:
   2095                 indexers.append(self.obj.index.get_indexer(group.index))
   2096 

ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

What does it mean and how can it be resolved?

**EDIT:**
code to replicate the problem in pandas 0.12 stable

```
dff = pd.DataFrame({'A': list('222'), 'B': list('123'), 'C': list('123') })
dff.groupby('A').filter(lambda x: len(x) > 2)
```

Comment: Not sure how you got this, what is my_df? (can you provide some code to replicate this?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was a quasi-bug in 0.12 and will be [fixed in 0.13](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/blob/master/pandas/core/groupby.py#L2161), the res is now protected by a type check:

```
if isinstance(res,(bool,np.bool_)):
    if res:
        add_indices()
```

I'm not quite sure how you got this error however, the docs are actually compiled and run with actual pandas. You should ensure you're reading the docs for the correct version (in this case you were linking to dev rather than stable - although the API is largely unchanged).

The [standard workaround](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/919) is to do this using [transform](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/groupby.html#transformation), which in this case would be something like:

```
In [11]: dff[g.B.transform(lambda x: len(x) > 2)]
Out[11]: 
   A  B  C
0  2  1  1
1  2  2  2
2  2  3  3
```

Comment: Is there a way to overcome this in pandas 0.12? I am using pandas 0.12 stable. The link I provided was through a search I found online :\ I added an example that replicates the problem. Thanks